# Windows 10 stops after hibernation

Tags: laptop, windows-10, power, hibernate

I have a problem with my windows 10. It is convinient to me to hibernate my laptop, so it loads fast after that and everything is saved.

So I usually use hibernate. But when I installed windows 10 there is a problem.

Sometimes when I try to turn on laptop it starts loading (the balls start circling) and the freeze. I wait a 1-2 minutes, but nothing happens. So in this situations I have to long press power off button.

I don't know why this happens. Has anyone any idea ?